# Why is this loop looping the code but not performing the correct actions?

Tags: java

When I click retry on this code, it work's and asks how many times to loop flip a coin but the just prints "Flipping Coin(s)" and does nothing. Anyone know how to fix it? I think the error might be coming from X already being less than numloop but I am not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class coinFlip {

  public static void main (String[]args)throws InterruptedException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numloop;
    int x = 0;
    String choice;
    Boolean bool = true;


    while (bool=true){
      System.out.println("How Many Coins Would You Like To Flip?");
      numloop = sc.nextInt();

      if (numloop == 13 || (numloop == 5 || (numloop == 8 || (numloop == 666)))) {
        System.out.println("ILLUMINATI CONFIRMED ??????");
        System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.println("Flipping Coin(s)...");
      System.out.println();

      while (x<numloop) {

        int rng = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);

        if (rng <= 5) {

          System.out.println("You Flipped Heads");
        }

        else {
          System.out.println("You Flipped Tails");
        }

        x=x+1;
      }


      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Would You Like To 'Quit' Or 'Retry'?");
      choice = scan.nextLine();

      if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
        System.out.println ("Have A Nice Day");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.exit(0);
      }

      if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Retry")) {
        bool=true;
      }


    }
  }
}
```

Thank You So Much!

Answer (score 0):

If you move `int x=0` from outside of your initial while loop to inside of it you won't have this issue. It will reset every time the user retries.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numloop;

    String choice;
    Boolean bool = true;


    while (bool=true){
        int x = 0;
        System.out.println("How Many Coins Would You Like To Flip?");
        numloop = sc.nextInt();

        if (numloop == 13 || (numloop == 5 || (numloop == 8 || (numloop == 666)))) {
            System.out.println("ILLUMINATI CONFIRMED ??????");
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Flipping Coin(s)...");
        System.out.println();

        while (x<numloop) {

            int rng = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);

            if (rng <= 5) {

                System.out.println("You Flipped Heads");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("You Flipped Tails");
            }

            x=x+1;
        }


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would You Like To 'Quit' Or 'Retry'?");
        choice = scan.nextLine();

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
            System.out.println ("Have A Nice Day");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Retry")) {
            bool=true;
        }


    }
}
```